# Computation Operation in one Recurrence Relation

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, contest-math, recursive-algorithms, recursion

We want to calculate $T(n)$ from recurrence relation $ T(n)= \Sigma_{i=1}^{n-1} T(i) \times T(i-1)$` and we know $T(0)=T(1)=2$. How many computation operation, an Efficient Algorithm needs for calculate $T(n)$?

a) $O(n)$

b) $O( n lg n) $

c) $ O(n \sqrt{n}) $

d) $O(n^2)$

Comment: Have you tried computing some small values?  The three choices are not hard to tell apart.  Proving one correct may be harder.

Comment: Dear @RossMillikan, I think O(n).

Comment: This question ignores the fact that the numbers increase exponentially, and so it's not realistic to assume that arithmetic is $O(1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many terms are in the sum defining $T(n)$ as a function of $n$?  You need one multiply for each, then one less adds to do the sum.  The numbers $T(n)$ grow much faster-are you expected to account for that?

Comment: Dear @Ross, I'm not professional, would you please add more detail for me to learn it !?

Comment: To get the number of terms, you need to look at the limits of the summation.  If the summation ran from $1$ to $6$, there would be $6$ terms.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. so the final is O(N)?

Comment: Yes, it is not hard to get an explicit formula.

Comment: Dear @Ross, would you please let me some hints for getting formal formula for solving such question ?

Comment: As I suggested, there are $n-1$ terms in the sum.  Each one requires a multiply. Then you need $n-2$ additions to compute te sum, for a total of $2n-3$.

Comment: would you please insert in addition of your answer? I approve it. thanks for your kind.

Comment: Dear @Ross, 2n-3 or 2n-4 ?

Comment: There is one less addition than multiplication, so $2n-3$